# Generating QR code from an Input id="message2" automatically without the need of user clicking anything extra

Tags: javascript, api, input, qr-code

I am trying to generate a qr-code from the id="message2" automatically but it keeps coming back as undefined.

```js
     function generateBarCode()
            {
                var nric = $('#text').val();
                var url = 'https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=' + nric + '&amp;size=50x50';
                $('#barcode').attr('src', url);
            }
```

```html
<div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group mb-3" style="max-width: 400;">
                    <input style="color: blue;" type="text" class="form-control input-message2" id="new-myInput" value="" readonly="" onclick="select()" input="message2">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <button onclick="myFunction()" class="btn btn-primary copyit" data-clipboard-target="#address"><i class="far fa-copy"></i> Copy </button>
                               
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        
        
        <br>
    
    
        
        <input id="new-myInput" id="text" value="" input="message2" style="Width:100%" onblur='generateBarCode();' /> 

      <img id='barcode' 
            src="https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=HelloWorld&amp;size=100x100" 
            alt="" 
            title="Your Message In QR" 
            width="100" 
            height="100" />
```

There is no need for the second input I am just trying to get the qr code to generate automatically from the text that is being pulled on this line  `<input style="color: blue;" type="text" class="form-control input-message2" id="new-myInput" value="" readonly="" onclick="select()" input="message2">` but of course it is not displayed in code snippet, **I am using Laravel 5**

Comment: You shouldn't have `&amp;` in your URL string; it should be a plain `&`.  Also you should pass the text content (`nric`) through `encodeURIComponent()` before concatenating it into the URL.

Comment: Also you don't have to use `.attr()`; it'd be better to use `.prop()` to set the "src".

Comment: @Pointy would you mind helping on this occasion by removing the necessary things please

Comment: Also your `<input>` has two "id" values.

Comment: Can i merge those ids into one with a space?

Comment: No, id values cannot contain spaces.

Comment: no i was referring to something like this id="new-myInput text"

Comment: Again, no, because **id values cannot contain spaces**.

Answer (score 0):

Several things:

- In the JavaScript domain, it is not necessary to escape `&` in a string. In other words, you don't need `&amp;`; it should just be "&".
- The text to send to the QR service should be encoded for the URL by passing it through `encodeURIComponent()`
- Your text `<input>` has two "id" values, so the jQuery search won't find it.

Your function should look like this:

```
 function generateBarCode() {
   var nric = $('#text').val();
   var url = 'https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=' + 
       encodeURIComponent(nric) + 
       '&size=50x50';
   $('#barcode').prop('src', url);
 }
```

Comment: I should add that *sometimes* you may need HTML entity escapes in JavaScript strings; it depends on what the string is going to do. This is not one of those cases.

Comment: Thank you this is working now, but I must type in the data and then click off of the input field to get it to generate the QR, so I think now it is the issue with the message2 being automatically translated into a QR code, but thank you @pointy

Comment: You have to click off the input because that's how you designed the tool; the input calls the function on the "blur" event, which happens when the field loses focus.

Comment: I see, I am trying to find alternatives or just to comepletely remove that and have it change by jquery every character that is inputted

Comment: You could see if switching to `oninput` instead of `onblur` would do what you want.

Comment: thank you I have used the oninput event, but I still cannot get them to marry up and get the barcode to generate from message2, message 2 is a bitcoin wallet btw if that helps?

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. An "input" attribute in an `<input>` element is meaningless to the browser. It won't hurt anything, but it doesn't *do* anything either.

Comment: okay so i am trying to have the data from `id=message2` from the first `<input>` to be inside of the second input and onload generate the barcode, Im not sure if that is abit clearer or worse?

Comment: following that I would user `display:none;` on the second `<input>` so then its not visible and just have the barcode there because there is no need for message2 to be repeated twice